# Memory stuck in Solaris .. server can't free disk space

Tags: filesystems, svm, solaris, solaris-10, opensolaris

I am working on Solaris 11, Now facing problem related to memory As my root is reached to 90%, I have deleted the audit file from /var/share/audit which is of 8GB after deleting the file, server doesn't free that memory . Why? How can free that memory (disk space) without reboot the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the file you deleted named like  `20170220123456.not_terminated.<hostname>`? If so, probably the file handle is still held open by auditd. What does this command output:

```
pfiles $(pgrep auditd)
```

If it shows a file without a path it's probably the file you deleted. The easiest way to get rid of it would be by restarting auditd:

```
svcadm restart auditd
```